# Run script inside View after Document Loads - ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I've this code below in my View:

```
 @if (TempData["Success"] != null)
  {
    if ((bool)TempData["Success"] == true)
      {
       <script type="text/javascript">@Html.Raw("ShowUIModal('Success','Message Successfully Sent!');") </script>
      }
    else
      {
       <script type="text/javascript">@Html.Raw("ShowUIModal('Message sending Failed!!', 'Please try again!');") </script>
      }
  }
```

In chrome console it logs -"Object [object Object] has no method 'modal' ". I understand it's there because jquery-ui.js is not loaded the time above code is executed, because when I run this code individually after the View loads, it works fine:

```
ShowUIModal('Message sending Failed!!', 'Please try again!');   // it works fine after page loads.
```

So, how can I execute it after all the js files are loaded? Thanks a lot in advance, I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can try to do is, have a hidden input and its data-success attribute set by the TempData object and then, you can retrieve it via Jquery or JavaScript on DOM ready and show your Modal Popup.

```
<input type = "hidden" id="Status" data-success = @TempData["Success"]></input>
```

and in scripts tag in the head section of your page,

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var status = $('#Status').attr('data-success');
if(status == true){
// Your - ShowUIModal() here
}
else
{
// Your else code here
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the trick, modified a little and job done !! 
It was causing the modal to popup every time, hence I wrapped it up inside a function so the variable remains in closure and checked 'status.length' to be greater than 0 (if the hidden input exists) and it's working like a charm... thanks mate :)